# Only get whats in between the pattern using RegEx

Tags: c#, regex

Im currently using the following really simple regex {{(.*?)}} to find handlebars within a file..
However.. for some reason it keeps returning a result where the {{}} are included..
For instance:
Some  text {{Text}}

Woudl return two groups
1. {{Text}}
2. Text

Is there anyway in C# to make the Regex only return results like the 2:nd group?

Br,
Inx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to use lookarounds. You got two results mainly because of the capturing group. In C#, matched strings are stored inside group index 0 and the captures are stored inside the index with their  corresponding group number as index number.

```
@"(?<=\{\{).*?(?=}})"
```

Since the above regex does the matching operation only, you will get the desired string from group index 0.

Answer (score 2):

`Regex.Match` returns `Match` object, which has `Groups` so just make use of it.

It is by convention that group `0` **is the match**.

So, just do the below without changing your regex. Using lookaheads or behinds *isn't* advised as it affects the efficiency. Why not take group 1?

```
var match = Regex.Match(input, regex);
if(match.Success) {  // only if matching is successful
   Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1].Value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

string ptn = @"(?<={{).*?(?=}})";
string value = "{{ayhan}},{{mehmet}},{deneme}";
string[] result = Regex.Matches(value, ptn).Cast().Select(m => m.Value).ToArray();

**Output**
ayhan
mehmet